# Why so duplicate jars with time stamp? How to avoid it

Tags: java, maven

[tomcat project's libs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDRPm.png)

there have  duplicate jars with time stamp in my tomcat-libs. How to avoid it ?
config:

Comment: Please share your POM file.

Comment: And tell us what IDE is generating that screenshot

Comment: Oh,so sorry, it's my POM file,[link](https://github.com/Justhing/sharefile/blob/master/stackof/pom.xml)

Comment: @StephenC I used Intellij Idea. I can't find the process of generation.  Only run .

Comment: You are using SNAPSHOT's which are technically are jar's with timestamps...If you have duplicate entries you are bitten by a bug https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MWAR-427 temporarily you should simply use `mvn clean package`. I strongly recommend to update maven-compiler-plugin and also define maven-war-plugin with a fixed version or even better all plugins should be defined with an version in your pom file.

Comment: @khmarbaise  Thank you so much,it's fine when I updated maven-compiler-plugin . And  I remove the 'SNAPSHOT' in version definition.  ^v^ Thank you everybody!